# echo lines of file - but no more than N characters per line

Tags: cat, tail, text, head

I would like to print the `tail` of a file (could be also `head` or `cat` in general) to the screen but restrict the number of characters per line.

So if a file contains ...

```
abcdefg
abcd
abcde
abcdefgh
```

... and the maximum number is 5, then the following should be printed:

```
abcde
abcd
abcde
abcde
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tail yourfile |cut -c 1-5`
....

Comment: Note that in the case of current versions of GNU `cut`, that only works for single-byte characters (it returns only the first 5 bytes of each line). Hopefully, that will be fixed in a future version (some vendors like RedHat I believe have patches for that).

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
sed 's/\(.\{5\}\).*/\1/' file.txt
```

Comment: That is more readable with ERE: `sed -rn 's/(.{5}).*/\1/p' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

So many ways:

`grep`:

```
$ tail file.txt | grep -o '^.\{,5\}' 
abcde
abcd
abcde
abcde
```

`sed`:

```
$ tail file.txt | sed 's/^\(.\{,5\}\).*/\1/'
abcde
abcd
abcde
abcde
```

`awk`:

```
$ tail file.txt | awk '{print substr($0,1,5)}'
abcde
abcd
abcde
abcde
```